# Selecting single row in shiny using DT

Tags: r, shiny

Based on this [example](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-rows/),  I am trying to select only a single row and consequently highlight a single point.

I have changed the line datatable(cars) to datatable(cars,selection = 'single') as per the documentation which limits the selection to only one row.

However, after selecting more than once even though only one row is highlighted all previous points stay highlighted.

Is there a way of ensuring that only one row is returned from the selection i.e. that all previous selections are cleared?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a bug in **DT**, and I just [fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/commit/75e903b0357c7e466c0b10c402184ce313220519) it (sorry about that). There are two ways to solve the problem, and you can use either one:

1. Install the [development version](https://github.com/rstudio/DT) on Github;
2. Or use `renderDataTable(server = FALSE)` if your data object is not too big.

Comment: is it only still only in dev version?

Comment: @Userrrrrrrr Yes. I haven't worked on DT for a long time, and I'll try to make a new CRAN release this month.

Comment: @Yihui I'm very glad I found this item - I was having the same problem and it was very confusing. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @YihuiXie - was this fix ever released or is there a regressions?  We seem to now experience same issue using DT_0.24 under R version 4.2.0.